# backbone.js/marionette.js global region: body inside body

Tags: templates, backbone.js, marionette

In my index.html I've got empty `<body>` tag. I've got a view that loads content for the view (through icanhaz). I would like to have a global region (bound to body tag) and to put some contents inside it through a view. The problem I have is that it puts entire new body tag into existing body tag.

This is application:

```
var Application = new Marionette.Application();

Application.addRegions({
  bodyRegion: new Marionette.Region({el: "body"})
});

Application.addInitializer(function(options) {
    Application.bodyRegion.show(new RootView());
});
```

This is my rootView:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'body',

    initialize: function(options) {
        logger.init('root');
        loader.loadTemplate(template);
        this.headerView = new HeaderView();
        this.usersView = new UsersView();
    },

    render: function() {
        logger.render('root');
        this.$el.html(ich.rootTemplate);
        this.headerView.setElement(this.$el.find('#header')).render();
        this.usersView.setElement(this.$el.find('#main')).render();
        return this;
    }
});
```

This is my root.ich:

```
<script id="rootTemplate" type="text/html">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div class="container" id="main"></div>
</script>
```

The problem I've got is that after rendering I've got a  tag inside another  tag. If I don't use Marionette and use plain backbone views instead, with following lines:

```
var rootView = new RootView();
rootView.setElement('body').render();
```

everything works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`tagName: 'body',` creates a new `body` element (your second one). Use `el: 'body'` if your element has to be the body, `tagName` is used to create a new element for the views which don't have one.

Comment: then I get `Uncaught Error: HierarchyRequestError: DOM Exception 3` from the line `Application.bodyRegion.show(new RootView());`

Comment: Dunno Marionnette, I guess your view's element cant be the region's one?

Comment: No that doesn't seem to be that, but you definitely got some DOM insertion error.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the tagname declaration and you should be fine.
your view root view will inset itseft into the body ( your region el) creating a div for itself that will be its on el.

if a div is not acceptable and you need the region el to be the body then
change your region declaration

```
Application.addRegions({
    bodyRegion:"body" // this will create your new region just fine with body as its el
});
```

and your view should look like this...

```
Backbone.View.extend({
el: 'body',  // with this line your view will be atached to an existing element in this case the body.


initialize: function(options) {
    logger.init('root');
    loader.loadTemplate(template);
    this.headerView = new HeaderView();
    this.usersView = new UsersView();
},

render: function() {
    logger.render('root');
    this.$el.html(ich.rootTemplate);
    this.headerView.setElement(this.$el.find('#header')).render();
    this.usersView.setElement(this.$el.find('#main')).render();
    return this;
}
```

});